# Space of Non-Surjective maps between Spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $\text{Map}_{ns}(S^n,S^n)$ denote the space of all continuous, non-surjective maps from $S^n$ to $S^n$ carrying the compact-open topology. There is the following fibration:$$
\text{Map}_{ns}((S^n,N),(S^n,N))\to \text{Map}_{ns}(S^n,S^n)\to S^n
$$
where the last map is evaluation at the north pole $N$ and $\text{Map}_{ns}((S^n,N),(S^n,N))$ is the subspace of pointed non-surjective maps.

My question is wether evaluation at the north pole is a (weak) homotopy equivalence or in other words wether $\text{Map}_{ns}((S^n,N),(S^n,N))$ is (weakly) contractible. It might also be interesting wether it makes a difference if one restricts to smooth maps (I'm a bit hesistant to just cite smooth approximation in this case).

Comment: An element of $\pi_k$ consists of a map $S^{k+n}\to S^n$ for which none of the "equators" $S^n\to S^{k+n}\to S^n$ is surjective, up to homotopy(with a nonsurjectivity condition too); so you're looking at something related to $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ : the question might be difficult. Of course, any nonsurjective map is contractible so $\pi_0$ is trivial, but as soon as you start looking at $\pi_1$, you have stuff like $S^3\to S^2$, where there is the Hopf fibration (which does not, itself, satisfy the nonsurjectivity condition)

Comment: Is it obvious this is actually a fibration?

Comment: You can use the action of $O(n) $ on both spaces to show that it is a fiber bundle I think.

Comment: Is it true that $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is null-homotopic if and only if it is non-surjective? (One direction is clear). if so then $Map_{ns}(S^n,S^n)$ is simply the path-component of the constant map in $Map(S^n,S^n)$. The pointed version of this is the path-component of the constant map in the loop space $Map_*(S^n,S^n)=\Omega^nS^n$. Note that all path components of $\Omega^nS^n$ have the same homotopy type, and in particular are non-trivial when $n>1$.

Comment: @Tyrone There are surjective maps that are nullhomotopic. For example project the sphere onto a disk and map the disk surjectively to the sphere

Answer (score 2):

Smooth approximation does indeed show that the homotopy type doesn't depend on smoothness. The point is that the set of surjective maps is closed by compactness, and so given any compact family $f: X \times S^n \to S^n$ of non-surjective maps, the infimum $$D = \inf_x d(f_x, \text{Map}_{\text{surj}})$$ is strictly positive. Here distance is measured in $C^0$.

Because you can apply smooth approximation to any compact family while changing the $C^0$ norm by an arbitrarily small amount, you can in fact smoothly approximate while moving the whole family by $C^0$ norm less than $D$, so that you can't reach a surjective map by such a small perturbation.

The actual question you ask strikes me as hard but I bet it is false for $n > 1$. It strikes me that it is probably equivalent to whether or not there is a continuous map $r: \text{Map}^*_{ns}(S^n, S^n) \to S^n$ (the domain being pointed non-surj maps) with $$r(f) \not \in \text{Im}(f).$$ I do not have an idea for constructing that map.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the original question is equivalent to the existence of $r$ (but I agree having $r$ answers the question affirmatively.)  On the other hand, here is a sketch of a proof that there is no such $r$.  Start with a non-surjective $f$ defined as follows.  Surjectively map $S^n$ onto a rectangle, then wrap the rectangle around the equator in such a way that the image is $S^n$ without the two poles, $n$ and $s$.  Then $r(f)=n$ without loss of generality.  Now, create a homotopy $F$ of $f$ for which $F(\cdot, t)$ surjects onto $S^n\setminus\{s\}$ for all $t > 0$.  Then ....

Comment: $r(F(\cdot, t)) = \begin{cases} n & t = 0\\ s & t > 0\end{cases}$.  This is clearly not continuous.